# Script runs fine on JSFiddle, fails elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have no idea how to use the jQuery library. The same code works in a JSFiddle; here's the link for that: http://jsfiddle.net/NhhKd/.

Please some one let me know why the same code works in JSFiddle but not in plunker or any other site.

```js
$("#fruitList").sortable();

$("body").on('click', '#fruitList .delete', function () {
    $(this).closest(".fruit").remove();
});

$("#addFruit").click(function () {
    $('#fruitList').append("<li class='fruit'>New fruit<button class='delete'>Delete</button></li>");
});
```

```css
#fruitList {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style:none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width:150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding:20px;
}
.fruit {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    background:#eeeeee;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}
button {
    background:#eeeeee;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='addFruit'>Add fruit</button>
<ul id="fruitList">
    <li class="fruit">Apple
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li class="fruit">Banana
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li class="fruit">Orange
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I opened the console and seen the error saying that it is not a function. What do you suggest me to do Paul Roub

Comment: Actually include jQuery UI in your page (or plunker, etc.) as noted in the answer below.

Comment: For example, here it is [on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qHCVq4IG96oTwP4WFSEx?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked JSFiddle includes [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/).  Without that, you're missing `.sortable()`, as your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) should have alerted you.

The amended snippet below, include jQuery UI and a more-modern jQuery, works just like the JSFiddle.

```js
$("#fruitList").sortable();

$("body").on('click', '#fruitList .delete', function () {
    $(this).closest(".fruit").remove();
});

$("#addFruit").click(function () {
    $('#fruitList').append("<li class='fruit'>New fruit<button class='delete'>Delete</button></li>");
});
```

```css
#fruitList {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style:none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width:150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding:20px;
}
.fruit {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    background:#eeeeee;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}
button {
    background:#eeeeee;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id='addFruit'>Add fruit</button>
<ul id="fruitList">
    <li class="fruit">Apple
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li class="fruit">Banana
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
    <li class="fruit">Orange
        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Same script, running on CodePen (once jQuery UI was included): http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/zvLNda. The same should apply to plunker, etc.